# How does using sudo instead of su improve the security level?

Tags: ubuntu, security, sudo, su

Edit::
With the help of people, I realised I misunderstood the text and thought the creators Ubuntu also created `sudo`, which is not the case! So the question should be something like how forcing people to use `sudo` instead of `su` improve the level of security?

---

I am reading *The Linux Command Line* by *William Shotts*, and in **Permissions** section, he explains how Ubuntu introduced `sudo` to improve security. I'll include the entire text at the bottom.

The last paragraph confused me (and for context, in the previous paragraph, he says how abusing `su` command led to reduced the security level):

> When Ubuntu was introduced, its creators took a different tack. By default, Ubuntu disables logins to the root account (by failing to set a password for the account) and instead uses `sudo` to grant superuser privileges. The initial user account is granted full access to superuser privileges via `sudo` and may grant similar powers to subsequent user accounts.

So if the initial user account is granted **full access to superuser privileges via `sudo`**, then isn't it the same thing, basically?

1. Use `su` -> act as `root` -> full access to superuser privileges -> security concerns
2. Use `sudo` ---------------> full access to superuser privileges -> security concerns

I understand in using `sudo`, you don't need to know the password of `root` account, but if you have all privileges of root, it won't make any differences, will it?

Help needed! Thank you so much for your time and help in advance.

---

## Ubuntu and sudo

One of the recurrent problems for regular users is how to perform certain tasks that require superuser privileges. These tasks include installing and updating soft- ware, editing system configuration files, and accessing devices. In the Windows world, this is often done by giving users administrative privileges. This allows users to perform these tasks. However, it also enables programs executed by the user to have the same abilities. This is desirable in most cases, but it also permits malware (malicious software) such as viruses to have free rein of the computer.

In the Unix world, there has always been a larger division between regular users and administrators, owing to the multiuser heritage of Unix. The approach taken in Unix is to grant superuser privileges only when needed. To do this, the `su` and `sudo` commands are commonly used.

Up until a few of years ago, most Linux distributions relied on `su` for this purpose. `su` didn't require the configuration that `sudo` required, and having a root account is traditional in Unix. This introduced a problem. Users were tempted to operate as root unnecessarily. In fact, some users operated their systems as the root user exclusively, since it does away with all those annoying “permission denied” messages. This is how you reduce the security of a Linux system to that of a Windows system. Not a good idea.

When Ubuntu was introduced, its creators took a different tack. By default, Ubuntu disables logins to the root account (by failing to set a password for the account) and instead uses `sudo` to grant superuser privileges. The initial user account is granted full access to superuser privileges via `sudo` and may grant similar powers to subsequent user accounts.

From p.104 of the book *The Linux Command Line*, fifth internet edition, by *William Shotts*

Comment: Like, the problem was with abusing `su`, not with the command itself. So it feels like the problem is still there, only now people can abuse `sudo` which gives the same power as `su`?

Comment: I think your question makes no sense, since sudo predates ubuntu by about a quarter century, so, sudo wasn't introduced to ubuntu, it was always a part of ubuntu, so there's no "improvement" of any kind, since it's always been

Comment: Hey Jaromanda X, thank you for your comment. Right, I think I misunderstood the text and thought creators of Ubuntu also created sudo. So my question would be how does "disabling logins to the root account and instead using sudo" improves the security?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that being able to substitute user (`su`) as root and do a command as a substitute user (`sudo`) as root both allow you to access the powers of the root user.

Some differences that might be helpful in understanding the differences and how it might relate to security or system stability.

- `su` is usually used for running a shell as a different user
- `sudo` is usually used for running a single command as a different user

When running a single command as a privileged user, there is a single task that will be run. When running a shell, you now open up the possibility of making a mistake or additional changes while in that privileged mode.

As an analogy, imagine if you could summon the strength of 1,000 people at will. If you used that power all the time, you would have to be careful that you didn't cause damage when you opened a door, brushed your teeth, walked down a hallway, walked near someone on the street, or any of the myriad routine things you might have to do in a day. If instead, you only summoned that power for moving that very heavy object when you needed to and released the power when you completed the task, then you would be far less dangerous or likely to cause accidental harm.

Going back to the text you are quoting

> some users operated their systems as the root user exclusively, since it does away with all those annoying “permission denied” messages

This is like using your super power all the time. You are more likely to damage the system unintentionally which threatens the security depending on what you do.

Comment: Hey ParanoidGeek, Thank you for your reply! I think I understand it more clearly now, thanks to your and others' comments. So I guess it's really down to granting that superpower for a single command vs. become a superman. And I can imagine how much that will help in terms of system stability. I appreciate your help and loved the analogy :) always finds analogies very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't security in the sense of that your *can't* do damage, it's just that it breaks up bad usage patterns that made damage more likely.

"Back in the day", it wasn't that uncommon that people literally logged in as root in an X session. And that came with *a lot* of problems. Still, contemporary guides touted that as easy solution to problems that would actually have a proper non-root solution.

By simply making it impossible to log in as root, you'd force your user to do the right thing. Of course, the user could have set a root password using `sudo` and then still do the undesirable login, but it's an extra hoop they would have to jump through. That way, doing the right thing became easier (running just the one command that needs root privileges as root, out finding a way without root privileges), and doing the wrong thing for hard.

Note that Ubuntu by no means introduced or even popularized sudo (at least for me, and in my circles). Sudo was available and used on multiple Linux distros before Ubuntu got the market. It might be that Ubuntu 4.10 started out with an installer that didn't force you to set a root password, can't remember, but it was really not an unheard of idea that your root password be long and hard to remember, and that you use sudo in daily administrative work.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Yeah, I saw a lot of "installation guides" and what not, to just say "if there is an error, use sudo". That's a typical case of using sudo where there is a proper non-root solution, I guess.

Yeah I misunderstood that bit, that sudo always existed before Ubuntu and so this usage pattern probably did too.

Thank you again for sharing your knowledge and experience :)